# Выпад panel из panel c# winforms

Tags: c#, winforms

Всем добрый вечер. Я не знаю куда и как правильно писать, поэтому решил спросить у более умных людей, чем я.

Суть вопроса: Мне надо сделать выпад panel с текстом и другой рисовкой окна в windowsforms c#
Т.е. я нажал на кнопку "Револьеры" и из нее выпали другие типы. Нажал на кнопку "Usp" и оно отрисовало другой интерфейс. (ниже скрин с фигмы)
[image: Скрин с фигмы]

А вот скрин с моего VS

[image: vs studio скрин]

Мне не нужен прям весь код от человека (было бы не плохо, но очень по-наглому) А помощь с названием функций, чтобы уже разобраться самому :0

Comment: Обычно такой компонент называется Аккордеон - Accordion. По этому термину можно найти готовые реализации.

Comment: В WPF есть контрол Expander, в винформах такого не знаю. Знаю только чтобы вам сделать вертикальный стек из кнопок, потребуется `FlowLayoutPanel`. По-моему я уже говорил вам про нее.

Comment: Вот здесь https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3795005/add-an-expander-collapse-expand-to-a-panel-winform `SplitContainer` предлагают.